# EntityFramework creating extra columns

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following classes:

```
public partial class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Subscription> Followers { get; set; }
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Subscription> Following { get; set; }
}

public partial class Subscription
{
    [Key]
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Follower { get; set; }
    public virtual User Followed { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
}
```

The users table is generated fine but the Subscriptions table goes like this:

```
Subscriptions( SubscriptionId, status, Follower_UserId, Followed_UserId, 
User_UserId, User_UserId1 )
```

These two last columns are not necesary and they are getting in fact NULL values

Comment: Those columns are required for mapping. Problem is the column names are not meaningful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
public partial class Subscription
{
    [Key]
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Followers")]
    public virtual User Follower { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Following")]
    public virtual User Followed { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I also having similar issue, explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58408156/enitity-framework-each-property-name-in-a-type-must-be-unique . Not sure why its adds extra column. Tried with [InverseProperty("ResponseId")] on property ResponseId. Did not work for me